# Why does “expecto patronum” work on a boggart-dementor?

Tags: harry-potter, dementors

In the third book Lupin uses a boggart to practice expecto patronum with Harry. Why does this work? The boggart is simply changing its appearance to look like a dementor it is not actually becoming one?

Comment: @Ongo No. I want to know why it works at all. It’s a spell for dementors, not boggarts

Comment: Why do you think a spell that *works* on dementors is a spell *for* dementors?

Comment: I think the reason it works at all is that a boggart in the form of a dementor is a close enough simulation of a dementor to be affected by a Patronus - Harry hears his tormented past and falls unconscious when initially facing the boggart-dementor and Lupin remedies this with chocolate, which is the exact same chain of events that a *real* dementor causes. However, the simulation isn't perfect, it's still a boggart and still needs riddikulus to be defeated. If the simulation was perfect, we should have expected Lupin to transform in the presence of the boggart full moon, which he didn't.

Comment: I think I have an answer that answers this directly (referencing Non-Human Spiritous Apparitions as a class, how a Patronus interacts with boggarts/dementors/lethifolds, quotations from a few books and sources). It doesn't fit the linked question though. I don't have enough rep to vote to re-open, but I wondered what the general feeling was on this one — I do think there's a better answer than those available on the other question.  (I suppose I would — I wrote it!)

Comment: @BeginTheBeguine well if you've got a solid answer with quotes, then have a Re-open vote...

Comment: this feels different enough from the linked question - another re-open vote from me

Comment: Yes, please reopen. The other question asks why a boggart is useful as training object for Expecto Patronum, while this question is about whether a boggart is really affected by a Patronum, I think I have a good answer to that.

Answer (score 2):

Harry is only practising. It is not necessary to be in the presence of Dementor to produce a Patronus, as evidenced throughout the rest of the series when students are practising in the room of requirements, or when Patronuses are used to carry messages. It is sometimes, for some people, useful to be in the right frame of mind when learning a new skill.

> “Ah yes,’ said Lupin, when Harry reminded him of his promise at the end of class. ‘Let me see … how about eight o’clock on Thursday evening? The History of Magic classroom should be large enough … I’ll have to think carefully about how we’re going to do this … we can’t bring a real Dementor into the castle to practise on …”
>
> Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 12 (The Patronus)

This is Lupin realising the appearance of a Dementor is likely to be useful to Harry who over the series demonstrates a preference for practical over theory-based learning. (See his efforts with a Summoning Charm in GoF).